# Multiple Image change on mouseover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing a problem with a hover effect I'd like to have

On mouseover I'd like to change various images for each project. The first image is displayed, but all projects have the last array of the first project as hover.

What might be wrong? Would be great if you could help a bit.
In this fiddle it works perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/zgnd9w90/1/3

```
<div class="image">
    <?php

    $i = 0;
    $datasrc = '';

    foreach ($project->images()->shuffle()->limit(3) as $image)
    {
        if ($i == 0)
        {
            $datasrc .= $image->url();
        } else
        {
            $datasrc .= ',' . $image->url();
        }
        $i ++;
    }
    ?>
    <figure class="img--container" data-image-list="<?php echo $datasrc ?>">
        <img class="img--hover" src="<?php echo $project->images()->first()->url() ?>"
             alt="<?php echo $project->title()->html() ?>">
    </figure>

</div>
```

and here is the jQuery snippet

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').mousemove(function (event) {

        var xPos = event.pageX;

        $images = $(this).parents('figure').eq(0).data('imageList');

        var array = $images.split(',');

        if (xPos > 100) {
            $(this).attr("src", array[0]);
        }
        if (xPos > 200) {
            $(this).attr("src", array[1]);
        }
        if (xPos > 300) {
            $(this).attr("src", array[2]);
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideas how to fix the issue?
If i hover the images the console gives me the error "split" undefined. How can i solve that issue?

Comment: you're using the wrong tags, your css, javascript and jquery code is working perfectly, add the php tag so you might get proper help

Comment: So why you do not use that fiddle?